# Placing two different images on hover with two center images side by side

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to HTML in the past month. I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to change the second image on hover to be a different image when the mouse hovers over it. I know some of the code probably looks dumb with how I tried to guess how I could possibly alter the second hover image. But I am quite confused. If anyone could help that would be great. The only progress I made so far is finally getting them perfectly aligned the way I would want them in the center and also the smooth transition to the hover. All that is left is being stumped on how to change the image to a different one when you hover over the second image. I do not want both hover images to be the same.

```css
* {
  background-color: coral;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  /* a way to add a space around */
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .container {
    /* make them full-width and one-a-row */
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

.image {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: all .4s ease-in;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-image: url("sketchcollage.JPG");
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40%;
}

.overlay .overlay2 {
  background-image: url("digitalartcollage.JPG");
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container:hover .image {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(12, 215, 230), rgb(170, 9, 130));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1> Who is Rosalyn? </h1>
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://trezoro.co">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="Le Tricolore Smartwatch" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>Entire element is the link here</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="Le Tricolore Smartwatch" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <a href="https://trezoro.co">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay2">
    <p>Only the text is a link </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is `p` tags are for, so I removed those. Also, I used a `div` with `background-image` instead `img` tag. when you hover on the `container`, the image changes.

```css
* {
  background-color: coral;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50vh;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 48%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .flex{
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
.img{
  background-size: 100% 100%; 
  transition: all .4s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.img1{
  background-image: url('https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg');
}
.img2{
  background-image: url('https://s4.uupload.ir/files/717195_346_g0du.jpg');
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.container:hover .img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.container:hover .img1{
  background-image: url('https://s4.uupload.ir/files/0.270967001322580170_jazzaab_ir_ajvv.jpg');
}
.container:hover .img2{
  background-image: url('https://s4.uupload.ir/files/7560b48482bfae5c-02b97ffc647f-3822363654_tji3.jpg');
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(12, 215, 230), rgb(170, 9, 130));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1> Who is Rosalyn? </h1>
<div class="flex">
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://trezoro.co">
    <div class="img img1"></div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="img img2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was wondering what happened to the contents of overlay? How do you keep the contents of overlay? 

Also, I’m a bit lost on how the classes “Img” and “img1 and “img2” apply because in the HTML code you named then “img img1” and”img img2” doesn’t that register as a different name?

Comment: @CollegeStudent101 You did not explain the contents of overlay, so I did think maybe not be a need for that. I used `img1` and `img2` for creating two different pictures. because you said not want two pictures to be the same.

Comment: Oh it’s just for stylistic purposed and I wanted to keep it. Is it possible to be done still with overlay? 

Also, I’m still not clear why you named the div class for example,  “img img2” instead of just saying “img2”

Comment: @CollegeStudent101 Oh yes I understood your mean. `img` is for common styles for both(e.g `position` or `bg-size`) this is to reduce the amount of code. `img1` and `img2` are for specific backgrounds of each of those. about `overlay` what is your purpose about those? how do you want them to appear?

Comment: it would pretty much be a color overlay that appears over the changed image to make it look more like it was hovered over. i'm testing it out now and the problem I'm running into is when I try and do `.container:hover .overlay` I still do not get the overlay result.

Comment: @CollegeStudent101 If I do understand correctly, for your case no need to overlay at all. you need only to `opacity`. I edited my answer. do you want this?

Answer (score 0):

***QUESTION***

How to change the second image on hover to be a different image when the mouse hovers over it?

***ANSWER***

The approach of this question is to change an image when the user hovering the mouse over it. This task can be simply done by using the CSS background-image property in combination with the :hover pseudo-class to replace or change the image on mouseover.

```css
.changeImg:hover {
      background-image: 
           url("https://images.app.goo.gl/gfRnCCBPH6r4v3kp6");
}
```

Comment: Would “change image” be another class under “div container” in the HTML code or a new, desperate class that’s independent of the other classes ?

Comment: It should be with the div or any other element on which when you hover the current image or text or any other content on that element, it changes to some other image, text, or content.

Comment: Ok makes sense. With “change image”, how do you keep the contents of overlay? Because I think overlay also adds an effect to it as well

Comment: It doesn’t change the image? And also it moves the seconds image upwards? Probably because it doesn’t take all the positioning fixes that the other components have. A bit confused…